# Simple Place Autocomplete Edit Text Not working for Android

Tags: java, android, json, autocomplete

I have a place autocomplete edittext in my app and it is not working. I keep getting the error.

```
   jsonResults=   { "predictions" : [], "status" : "invalid_request" } for place autocomplete
```

The android developer says that if you get an invalid request it means that your input parameter is missing.

I checked my input parameter:

```
try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components;=country:us");
        sb.append("&input;=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I am typing things into the autocomplete edittext and it is not working my input seems to be fine.

Comment: Does it really need ";" in your parameter ??

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the android api key?
You have to create a browser API-key for this to work in your app.

Try it and see.